# Unable to run Teamviewer on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, teamviewer

I seemed to install it successfully, but when I attempted to launch it kept throwing errors:

Ran with su then got this:

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Starting network process (no daemon)
terminate called without an active exception
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/tvw_exec: line 40:  4093 Aborted                 "$TV_BIN_DIR/teamviewerd" -n -f
Network process already started (or error)
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

A box popped up after a minute saying:

> The TeamViewer daemon is not running! Please start the daemon (needs root permissions) before running TeamViewer.

```
teamviewer --daemon start
```

If you did not disable the daemon, please contact Teamviewer support

Run the following Command to obtain all log files

```
teamviewer --ziplog
```

I did that and have a zip file that I don't know what to do with.. Also, the support claims they can't help me without a license...

What can I do about this?

I'm on linux mint 18.1 Serena Cinnamon 64-bit

If you want the zip file, let me know.

EDIT1: Also, for some reason, it tried to launch again 20 hours after I'd left it alone... it was confusing and a little alarming... I did get it from the official website so...

Comment: sudo: teamviewer: command not found

Comment: apt-cache policy teamviewer
teamviewer:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     12.0.71510 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: sudo apt-get purge teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teamviewer:i386*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: (Reading database ... 475066 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (12.0.71510) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libjpeg62.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg62:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjpeg62:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 80.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 187 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Comment: Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 libjpeg62 i386 1:6b2-2 [80.5 kB]
Fetched 80.5 kB in 0s (147 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg62:i386.
(Reading database ... 475361 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg62_1%3a6b2-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg62:i386 (1:6b2-2) ...
Setting up libjpeg62:i386 (1:6b2-2) ...
Setting up teamviewer:i386 (12.0.71510) ...

Comment: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Comment: teamviewer

Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...

Comment: What's with all of the errors... are they going to affect my program? What can I do about them?

Comment: It's running however, I'm worried about the issues those installation errors will cause down the line. Is the best that can be done for now?

Comment: 1. you should update your original question with additional information and not add it into comments 2. if one of the answers solved your problem then you should select them as the solution. If an answer helped you but didn't solve your problem then you should upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
apt-cache policy teamviewer
```

showed:

> ```
> teamviewer:i386:
>  Installed: (none)
>  Candidate: (none)
>  Version table: 
> ***12.0.71510 0 100
>       /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```

The installation has not gone well. Just stating the fact it was partially installed.

---

There was obviously a missing dependency:

```
libjpeg62:i386
```

Which has been remedied by a reboot and:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

So the missing dependency is now in place, no further action required. And the TeamViewer will be running just fine now.

Comment: For my Xubuntu 22 it helps!
`sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed the issue on Ubuntu:

```
 1. sudo teamviewer repo preview
 2. sudo apt-get update
 3. sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You may face some issue while update, then you may need to run the following as well:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```